# Palavra portuguesa para "impeachment"?

Tags: tradução, tradução-inglês

Reparei que a [Wikipedia em português](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impeachment) usa frequentemente a palavra inglesa «impeachment».

Mas eu me pergunto: existe alguma palavra específica em sua língua? É comum o uso de *impugnação de mandato*?

Comment: É uma boa pergunta. Também eu me tenho interrogado sobre isso.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A [constituição federal brasileira](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/Constituicao/Constituicao.htm) fala de «autorização de processo» (art. 51), «processo», «julgamento» e «condenação» por «crimes de responsabilidade» (art. 52, I), consoante a fase do processo.

Portanto, seguindo a linguagem do documento, poderíamos falar em «processo por crime de responsabilidade».

Como são muitas palavras, *impedimento* (ver [significado 5. do Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/impedimento) e [também aqui](http://linguagista.blogs.sapo.pt/impeachmentimpedimento-1736435)) e *(processo de) destituição* são termos frequentemente usados nos média, o último preferencialmente em Portugal.

Comment: Interessante! Qualquer razão para isso não está sendo usado pelos meios de comunicação na situação política atual? Eles parecem estar usando o termo Inglês.

Comment: É possível que seja «para conferir carisma ao processo» (comentário do colonista citadado no blogue do Helder Guégués) ou (como diz um comentador) porque «impedimento» (de exercer o cargo) se parece referir mais à eventual punição e não ao processo. Provavelmente um pouco dos dois.

Answer (score 3):

A palavra sería **impedimento** como em francês empêchement, a origem da palavra em inglês.